# Function of this voltage regulator circuit?

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

Working on a data over power bus system, I've seen the following circuit in the power decoupling circuitry. If I am right, it gives a regulated output voltage by means of the Zener diode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7KPdE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- V<sub>BUS</sub> = 15 V
- V<sub>ZD1</sub> = 8.2 V

And:

- V+ - V<sub>out</sub> = GND - V-
- V<sub>out</sub> ~ V<sub>Z</sub> - (V<sub>beQ1</sub> - V<sub>beQ2</sub>) ~ 7 V; Respecting to GND, assuming that V<sub>beQ1</sub> = V<sub>beQ2</sub> = 0.6 V

I have seen other circuits than outputs a regulated voltage using a Zener diode and a mid power transistor ([Transistor Series Regulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139776/transistor-series-regulator)) having the same negative reference or GND.

My question is: why set a difference between GND and (over) V-? Does it have to deal with the data AMI encoding?

If I am wrong or need more information, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: This circuit is essential symmetric which may be benefit when attempting to get data from the power lines.

Comment: I'm guessing that there is a transformer upstream of this circuit and so the choice of GND reference is OK as the circuit is floating wrt ground. The signal modulation is filtered by the 1mH inductors and is coming in on a balanced line for noise immunity. As mentioned the symmetrical design is to cater for the balanced power and signal bus inputs.